# ExpressJs JWT secret or public key must be provided

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, express-jwt

I would like to make check-auth but return to me

> JsonWebTokenError: secret or public key must be provided

I can take token successful

how can i fix this?

I am following this tutorial ;

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Ip0pcwbWYM&t=633s

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    console.log(token);
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY);
    req.userData = decoded;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(401).json({
      message: 'Auth failed'
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: have you declared `JWT_KEY` value in a separate js archive? Like `nodemon.json` if you're using nodemon `{
    "env": { "JWT_KEY": value } }`

Comment: Glad it helped. Made a complete answer with some context regarding your question and you may vote if its useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`process.env` global variable is injected by the Node at runtime for your application to use. You need to create a new `env` file to store those environment variables.

That said, You must declare your variable `JWT_KEY` inside a separate js archive. If you're using Nodemon just create a archive `nodemon.json` (works like env in this case) and declare your variables like this:

```html
{ 
"env": { 
  "JWT_KEY": value,
  ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I already have `nodemon.json` with same pattern code with my JWT_KEY there. Still i am getting that error. Any idea where I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

put "" + before the process.env.JWT_SECRET
example
"" + process.env.JWT_SECRET